# I just achieved rank 20 in Hearthstone can I still get the card back even though its 31 of july?

Tags: hearthstone

I recently got rank 20 in Hearthstone. Will I still get the card back for July 2015?

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

Card backs are given out at the end of the season, at the start of the new month. The new season doesn't start for another day.